# MAPISendMail - Can't find MAPI_DIALOG_MODELESS - C++

Tags: mapi

```
Language: C++
```

I am using MAPI_DIALOG_MODELESS in MAPISendMail to open outlook draft as a modeless dialog
`result = MAPISendMail(0, 0, &message, MAPI_DIALOG_MODELESS, 0);`

Although, after importing Office 2010, I am not able to find MAPI_DIALOG_MODELESS and use it in my code. It seems it is not supported from Office 2010 and later. Therefore, I am forced to use the following:
`result = MAPISendMail(0, 0, &message, MAPI_DIALOG, 0);`

The problem with the above is that it opens a Model dialog of Outlook, and I cannot use outlook or my app until I close/perform an action in this dialog of Outlook.

Is there a way to open Modeless Outlook Dialog other than using MAPI_DIALOG_MODELESS? Or any reference/documentation of MAPI_DIALOG_MODELESS and why it has stopped working now?